# Ubuntu - View data Lines 10 by 10

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu

I need to write a script to view /etc/passwd 10 by 10 with pages numbers under. So it will display the next 10 lines after pressing a button. What command should I use? Have tried to check awk, head,tail, command but no luck finding a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash 

awk -F":" 'BEGIN { print "--------------------------------------------------"
                    printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n","USERNAME","GUID","DIRECTORY" 
                    print "--------------------------------------------------" 
                 } 
           NR==1, NR==10 {printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n", $1, $4, $7} ' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Usually a bit more effort from your side would help. A few hints on how you could start (one of many options). 1) `sed -n "i,jp" file` will print lines i to j - dynamically set i and j ; 2) use `wl -l` to get the total line number and compute total pages with this ; 3) use bash `read` to wait for user input to go to the next page. -----

Again one of many approaches - in this case by making your own bash script. Another one might include `split` which allows splitting files by lines.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output

Comment: hi and thanks. im sorry, im really new onto this,  currently end up on this script.  but needs this to be list all the user, but showing it by 10 

#!/bin/bash

awk -F":" '

BEGIN {
print "--------------------------------------------------"
printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n","USERNAME","GUID","DIRECTORY"
print "--------------------------------------------------" }
NR==1, NR==10 {printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n", $1, $4, $7} ' /etc/passwd

Comment: After the edits I think it's a good question and while it would be more easy to achieve with other tools, `awk` can do that just fine without the need for other tools or loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `getline rc < "-"` for each 10th line. To suppress a newline, move the cursor one line up with `system("tput cuu1")`:

```bsh
awk -F":" '
    BEGIN { print "--------------------------------------------------"
            printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n","USERNAME","GUID","DIRECTORY" 
            print "--------------------------------------------------" }
    !(NR%10) { getline rc < "-"; system("tput cuu1") }
    { printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n", $1, $4, $7 }
' /etc/passwd
```

To add page number you could use:

```
awk -F":" -v TNR=$(wc -l < /etc/passwd) '
    BEGIN { NUM_PAGES=TNR/10+1
            print "--------------------------------------------------"
            printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n","USERNAME","GUID","DIRECTORY" 
            print "--------------------------------------------------" }

    !(NR%10) { PAGE++
               printf "--- Page %d of %d ---",PAGE,NUM_PAGES
               getline rc < "-"; system("tput cuu1") }

    { printf "%-20s %-10s %-3s\n", $1, $4, $7 }
' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: thank you so much! you are such a blessing